# Android BaseInputConnection Dummy Mode

Tags: android

Looking at this [article](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/BaseInputConnection.html) it mentions a dummy mode but I can't find any explanation of what "dummy mode" is.

Comment: There's a couple mentions of it in the source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/fb9023359a546eaa93d7753c0c1af37f8d859111/tests/tests/view/src/android/view/inputmethod/cts/BaseInputConnectionTest.java#155

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/fb9023359a546eaa93d7753c0c1af37f8d859111/tests/tests/view/src/android/view/inputmethod/cts/BaseInputConnectionTest.java#205

Answer (score 0):

Based on the source link from John Douglas Dummy Mode refers to when base input connection is implemented with the second parameter as being false.

```
BaseInputConnection dummyConnection = new BaseInputConnection(mView, false);
```